# Display Array List of Objects in JSF table

Tags: java, jsf, jpa, jsf-2

I want to display ArrayList of objects into JSF table:

I created this Object:

```
public List<TData> td = new ArrayList<TData>();

    public class TData {

        private long id;
        private String key;
        private String language;
        private String translation;

        public TData(){};

        public TData(long id, String key, String language, String translation) {
            // super();
            this.id = id;
            this.key = key;
            this.language = language;
            this.translation = translation;
        }

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public void setKey(String key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        public String getLanguage() {
            return language;
        }

        public void setLanguage(String language) {
            this.language = language;
        }

        public String getTranslation() {
            return translation;
        }

        public void setTranslation(String translation) {
            this.translation = translation;
        }

    }

    public List<TData> getDataObj() {
        return td;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadData() {

        String query = "SELECT c FROM TranslationTestEntitie c";
        List<Object> result =  dao.jpqlQuery(query, 1, 0);

        for(int i =0; i < result.size(); i++){
            TranslationTestEntitie test = (TranslationTestEntitie) result.get(i);
            td.add((TData) result.get(i));

        }

    }
```

Then I use this datatable to display the result;

```
<h:dataTable value="#{languageBeanTest.dataObj}" var="o">

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Id</f:facet>
                    #{o.id}
                </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">key</f:facet>
                    #{o.key}
                </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">language</f:facet>
                    #{o.language}
                </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">translation</f:facet>
                    #{o.translation}
                </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: callflow.cfdbc_common.entities.TranslationTestEntitie cannot be cast to callflow.ccadmin.beans.LanguageBeanTest$TData
```

I get the result from the DB as List of Objects. How I can display these Objects into JSF page?

P.S This is the source code of the entitie

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Translations")
public class TranslationTestEntitie extends AbstractEntityWithId {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2029240552230401080L;

    @Column(name = "id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "key", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private String key;
    @Column(name = "language", insertable=false, updatable=false)

    private String language;
    @Column(name = "translation", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private String translation;

    public TranslationTestEntitie() {
    }

    // Getters and setters
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    //@Transient    Field will not be saved in database
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public String getTranslation() {
        return translation;
    }

    public void setTranslation(String translation) {
        this.translation = translation;
    }

}
```

I suppose that the Object returned by the JPA will be the same as the TData because I have the same object attributes.

Comment: Why don't you use a List<TranslationTestEntitie> instead of List<TData>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparantly, the objects returned are of type TranslationTestEntitie, and not of TData. You'll need to write the code to transform a TranslationTestEntitie into an object of type TData.

```
TranslationTestEntitie test = (TranslationTestEntitie) result.get(i);
TData newTData = new TData(test.getId(), test.getKey(), test.getLanguage(),  test.getTranslation());
td.add(newTData);
```

If it has the same fields anyway, why can't you use the TranslationTestEntitie itself?

```
List<TranslationTestEntitie> td=  new ArrayList<TranslationTestEntitie>();

for(int i =0; i < result.size(); i++){
        TranslationTestEntitie test = (TranslationTestEntitie) result.get(i);
        td.add(test);
}
```

Comment: I updated the post. The two objects have the same attributes.

Comment: That doesn't change the answer :) You'll have to write a method that creates a new TData object with the values from your TranslationTestEntitie object.

Comment: I'm new to this technology, would you please give me some more information how I can solve this problem.

Comment: `If it has the same fields anyway, why can't you use the TranslationTestEntitie itself?` How I can do that?

Comment: You can create a List of TranslationTestEntitie (instead of TData), and simply add your result to it in the loop.

Comment: If it's very little code would you show me how it can be done?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26553/discussion-between-stijn-haus-and-peter-penzov)